# conditionally combine anypublisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am working on an Interactor file where I make decision to fetch some objects from local storage if available otherwise from remote storage.
This interactor is called from ViewModel, so my data flow is like following:

```
ViewModel(GetCode()) >> Interactor(GetCode()-> AnyPublisher<String, Error>) >> Local/Remote Storage -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error>)
```

Now in interactor it will first check if the code is already in local database as following:
**LocalDataSourceProvider:**

```
func fetchCode(id: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error>
```

If it is not present in local database(returned nil above), get it from remote database(api call) with following
**RemoteDataSourceProvider:**

```
func fetchCode(id: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error>
```

How do I process above local and remote calls in my interactor method?

**Updated code after making changes mentioned by Fabio:**

```
local.fetchCode(voucherId).flatMap {
            if let code = $0 {
                return Just(code).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            return remote.fetchCode(Id: Id).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
```

Now I am getting following error in flatMap:

> No 'flatMap' candidates produce the expected contextual result type
> 'AnyPublisher<String?, Error>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** You just need to help the compiler a bit and I didn't add all the details before.

`flatMap` is what you need:

```
local.fetchCode(id: "id").flatMap { code -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> in
  if let code = code {
    return Just(code)
      .mapError { $0 as Error }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  } else {
    return remote.fetchCode(id: "id")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Tried your code but I am getting following error: No 'flatMap' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyPublisher<String?, Error>'. I have updated my code

Comment: Now getting: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<String, Error>, AnyPublisher<String?, Error>>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<String?, Error>'

Comment: Where are you using this code? It seems like it's a function that should return `AnyPublisher<String?, Error>`. So you need to add `.map(Optional.some)` and `eraseToAnyPublisher()` at the end of the chain.